# Reducing the System of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

\begin{align*}
x+2y-3z&=4 \\
3x-y+5z&=2 \\
4x+y+(k^2-14)z&=k+2
\end{align*}

I started doing the matrix of the system:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\ 3 & -1 & 5 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 & k^2-14 & k+2  \end{pmatrix} $$

But I still don't know how can I reduce this, could you explain me what steps I should follow?

Which values of $k$ make the system inconsistent, determined, undetermined?

Comment: Do you know how to do this sort of thing when the matrix just contains plain numbers?  If so, the $k$ really does not make any difference at all.  You just have to do a bit of algebra instead of arithmetic.

Comment: ... and the $k$s still don't matter since all the pivoting for row reduction occurs in the first two columns...

Comment: I think considering these as planes and thinking of them as intersecting,overlapping and parallel should be more easier.

Comment: What do you know about determinants and Cramer's rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us name the $3$ by  $3$ matrix of the coefficients as $A$ and the $3$ by $1$ matrix of the constants as $B$. And the matrix that you have provided becomes augmentation of two, name it $C = ([A|B])$

The system is said to be **consistent**, if we can find *at least one solution*, otherwise we say it **inconsistent**. To get an idea of consistency, find the determinant of $A$

- If $det (A) \neq 0$ , you have a unique solution and is consistent.
- If $det (A) = 0$ , it can have either no solution (*which is inconsistent*) or infinitely many solutions (*which is consistent*).

To proceed further with $det (A) = 0$ condition:

- If $Rank(A) \neq Rank(C)$, you have no solution.
- If $Rank(A) = Rank(C) < n$ (the size of $A$), you have infinitely many solutions. *(If $Rank(A) = Rank(C) = n$,  you have a unique solution)*

You need to reduce the matrix so that you can find the **Rank** easily (otherwise, in my opinion, reducing the matrices is not going to help). The transformations you need to perform are :

- $R_2 = R_2-3R_1$, it would make $A[2][1]$ as $0$.
- $R_3 = R_3 - 4R_1$, it would make $A[3][1]$ as $0$.
- Continuing so, you should reduce the given matrix to an Upper Triangular matrix (reducing to Upper Triangular form will help you to find the *Rank* of the matrix)

Comment: How can i find the determinant, it isn´t olny for square matrix?

Comment: A is a square matrix because it is made up of coefficients. The last column (of the matrix provided in question) has been excluded.

Comment: Oh i see, so i calculate the determinant and see where it goes to zero, which is 4 and -4

Comment: Exactly. And finding the rank solves it further.

Answer (score 3):

Let our augmented matrix be $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\ 3 & -1 & 5 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 & k^2-14 & k+2  \end{pmatrix}$$ as you pointed out. So, if we do $$-3R_1+R_2\to R_2~(I),~~~ -4R_1+R_3\to R_3~(II),~~~R_2-R_3\to R_3~(III)$$ then we get $$A\to B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & -3 & 4 \\ 0 & -7 & 14 & -10 \\ 0 & 0 & 16-k^2 & -k+4  \end{pmatrix}$$ Now think about

- $k=4$ which makes your system consistent with infinitely many solutions,
- $k=-4$ which makes your system inconsistent,

and...

Comment: In $R_2 (I)$, the second entry shouldnt be $-7$ because $(-3)(2)+(-1)=-7$

Comment: @VictorFranciscoSalazarGarci: Yes. It's a bad typo. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For sure, the most elegant manner would consist in a solution based on matrix calculations, noting that, as pointed out by Eric Towers, $k$ is just a number.

There is also a more basic solution which consists in variable elimination. From the first equation, you can extract $x$ as a function of $y$ and $z$. Plugging the so obtained  expression of $x$ into the second equation gives you an expression in which only appear $y$ and $z$; then, you can extract $y$ as a function of $z$. Now, plug all previous results into the third equation. After simplifications, you arrive to $$(k-4) ((k+4) z-1)=0$$ from which you can observe what B.S. wrote.

If you are not in these critical situations, then the solution for $z$ is immediate and going backwards, you find the corresponding $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very different from other answers. And I think that the approach using Gaussian elimination is more systematic. I wanted to show how this can be done with a little of *guesswork*.

---

If you notice that the sum of the first two equations is $4x+y+2z=6$, then you see that every solution of your system also fulfills the equations
\begin{align*}
4x+y+2z&=6 \\
4x+y+(k^2-14)z&=k+2
\end{align*}
Now if you subtract these equations you get:
$$(k^2-16)z=k-4$$
which is the same as $(k-4)(k+4)z=(k-4)$.

If $\boxed{k=4}$, then this last equation is $0=0$ and you system is equivalent to the system
\begin{align*}
x+2y-3z&=4 \\
3x-y+5z&=2 
\end{align*}

If $\boxed{k=-4}$, then the this equation is $0=-8$, and the system does not have solution.

If $\boxed{k\ne\pm4}$, then the original system is equivalent to the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
x+2y-3z&=4 \\
3x-y+5z&=2 \\
(k^2-16)z&=k-4
\end{align*}
Since $k^2-16\ne0$, the variable $z$ is uniquely determined by the last equation. Since the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is regular, the values of $x$ and $y$ are the also uniquely determined.